# Add parameter name to gravity forms

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity form. I have more 400 forms. I want to add a parameter name in every form and in a particular field. I know how to add the parameter in a Gravity form field.

But i want to add parameter in each form like search replace. Is there any trick available for Gravity form. Because it is so time taking to add a parameter name in each form.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render', function( $form ) {
    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
        // if( field you want ) {
        $field->allowsPrepopulate = true;
        $field->inputName = 'your_parameter';
        // }
    }
}, 9 );
```

You will need to determine the best way to identify the fields you wish to apply this to. You'll see I've left the condition commented out. If they all have the same field ID you could do:

```
if( $field->id == 1 ) { ... }
```

If they'll have the same label, you could do:

```
if( $field->label == 'My Label' ) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for support, Will it change all my fields once i run ?

Comment: Yes but not permanently. You would need to leave the code in place indefinitely for this to work.

Comment: I need permanently. Is there any trick to add in db permanently.

Comment: Nope. It's all stored in serialized arrays. It may be possible but it'll be messy. The solution I proposed is probably more ideal because if you ever need to disable it or modify it, you can do so to all forms from a single bit of code.